# A borderless X11 DIALOG window background is not correctly drawn

Tags: c++, linux, background, window, x11

I am trying to create a border-less window with a background that occupies the entire area of the window. The window size is **685x336** and the same is the background size. The problem is that, on the vertical axis of the window, the background is drawn only on the space occupied by the (window height - title bar height). At the bottom of the window the background is repeated, on the space that was occupied by the title bar.
Something like this:
[image]

I am creating the window and applying these changes to it:

```
Screen* DisplayScreen = NULL;
DisplayScreen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);
enum
{
    WM_HINTS_FUNCTIONS = (1L << 0),
    WM_HINTS_DECORATIONS =  (1L << 1),

    WM_FUNC_ALL = (1L << 0),
    WM_FUNC_RESIZE = (1L << 1),
    WM_FUNC_MOVE = (1L << 2),
    WM_FUNC_MINIMIZE = (1L << 3),
    WM_FUNC_MAXIMIZE = (1L << 4),
    WM_FUNC_CLOSE = (1L << 5)
};

struct WindowHints
{
    unsigned long flags, functions, decorations, status;
    long input_mode;
};

Atom wmHintsProperty = XInternAtom(d, "_MOTIF_WM_HINTS", 0);
struct WindowHints hints;
hints.flags = WM_HINTS_DECORATIONS;
hints.decorations = 0;
XChangeProperty
(
    d, 
    window, 
    wmHintsProperty, 
    wmHintsProperty, 
    32,
    PropModeReplace, 
    (unsigned char *)&hints, 
    5
);

Atom WindowType = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
Atom DialogType = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG", False);
XChangeProperty(
    d, 
    window, 
    WindowType, 
    XA_ATOM, 
    32, 
    PropModeReplace, 
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&DialogType), 1
);
```

This would create a border-less, plane window over which I apply the background. If I change it to a normal window then the background is correctly drawn over the entire width and height of it. When the border and title bar is removed then the space occupied by the title bar is not drawn at the bottom of the window (it's like the background is repeated).
What would cause this to happen?

Comment: X11 is quite complex. Why don't you use a toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)? Also, read carefully [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)

Comment: You forgot to show how you apply the background.